# Use of SimpleExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android, data-structures

I think this is fairly straightforward -- when using SimpleExpandableListAdapter, groups are populated via a List of Maps, and children are populated by a List of Lists of Maps. When you construct the adapter, you tell it the key to access the Maps with, like so:

```
new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
    this,
    createGroupList(), // returns List<Map>
    R.layout.category_row,
    new String[] { "Group Item" },
    new int[] { R.id.row_name },
    createChildList(), // returns List<List<Map>>
    R.layout.feed_row,
    new String[] { "Sub Item" },
    new int[] { R.id.row_name } 
);
```

My question is, say for a child, can I store extra data in this map and access it later? Say, could I put an additional key in the Map for a child, such as "Type"->"Premade" and access it later via the getChild() method of SimpleExpandableListAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can. Just extend SimpleExpandableListAdapter and override getView().

Comment: That's how I've been changing some settings for buttons. My concern wasn't so much with how to implement it as whether or not the Map would be cleared/modified at all and thus interfere with my code at some unexpected moment.