# How are the parameters in the SimpleExpandableListAdapter utilized?

Tags: android, android-layout, drop-down-menu, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I'm trying to make an Expandable List on the Android platform, and I find that I'm not understanding the parameters in the constructor.

I've consulted the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleExpandableListAdapter.html) and the constructor looks like this:

```
SimpleExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> groupData, int groupLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo, List<? extends List<? extends Map<String, ?>>> childData, int childLayout, String[] childFrom, int[] childTo)
```

Constructor

For `groupData` and `childData`, What exactly do the keys and the values in the Maps correspond to?

[This previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485402/use-of-simpleexpandablelistadapter) addresses only the general purpose of the parameters--I'd like to know specifically what the key and values within the constructor correspond to of the stuff that should end up on my list.

**Addendum:**

I should clarify - I mean what do the key-value pairs have to do with the list? For example, suppose I've got a list of categories - {Percussion, Woodwind} - and a list of sub-items: {Piano, Marimba} for Percussion and {Flute, Piccolo, Bassoon} for Woodwind. How do I set up the key-value pairs of the maps to make the ExpandableList display like my mock-up example below?

-Percussion:

```
 -Piano
 -Marimba
```

-Woodwind:

```
 -Flute
 -Piccolo
 -Bassoon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example: http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-game-programming/simple-expandable-list-example/

BTW, it's easier to simply create your own adapter by extending from `BaseExpandableListAdapter`; see 
http://about-android.blogspot.ca/2010/04/steps-to-implement-expandablelistview.html for an example.

This example has a problem with `getChildView()` and `getGroupView()`: It always creates a new View instead of reusing the View provided by the parameter `convertView` when it's not null.  See http://androidword.blogspot.ca/2012/01/how-to-use-expandablelistview.html for a more correct example as well as how to fill the adapter from a thread.

Comment: All good resources, though I cannot get the edumobile link to work. I've clarified my question. See the addendum - if you could answer it, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: www.edumobile.org is back on line, so you should be good to go.